# How can I enter the copy mode when I scroll the mouse while using Tmux in MinTTY?

Tags: tmux, wsl-2, mintty

Scrolling the mouse while using Tmux in MinTTY, the command history is scrolled.
It seems that MinTTY converts mouse scroll event to up/down key.

In the past, I tried the following terminal with tmux2.1 or later,
the terminal was automatically set to copy mode.

- iTerm2
- WindowsTerminal

The `.tmux.conf` options are all the same.
`set -g mouse on`

I want to stop sending up/down key when I scroll the mouse while using Tmux in MinTTY.
And if possible, I want to enter copy mode automatically like other terminals.

Current Environment:

- Ubuntu20.04 on WSL2
- MinTTY3.06(WslTTY,GitBash)

Comment: https://github.com/mintty/mintty/wiki/CtrlSeqs#mousewheel-reporting
Since I read this.
Sending an escape control signal to the terminal stopped it from being converted to an arrow key.

but Still no mouse scrolling to copymode...

Answer (score 0):

temporary solution:

> I want to stop sending up/down key when I scroll the mouse while using Tmux in MinTTY.
> add this line to ~/.mintty

```
SuppressMouseWheel=scrollapp
```

> I want to enter copy mode automatically like other terminals.

`Shift + MousuWheel` worked.
`Shift` may depend on the [Options->Mouse->Modifier for overriding default] setting.